# CDN link for main.min.css of Boilerplate v5.2.0

Tags: html5boilerplate

I've not found any CDN link for main.min.css of Boilerplate.

Am I missing something? Can anyone help me to get that CDN link?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's not available via CDN.

Answer (score 0):

You can serve any (static) file through rawgit for CDN purposes.